# How would a nuclear blast affect me?

Tags: weapon-mass-destruction, nuclear-weapons

We all know what's a nuclear bomb, but how would a nuclear bomb affect the human body, for example, let's say a nuclear bomb as powerful as The Fatman  1000m away from me, **would I survive the blast?** If not how far would I need to be to survive the blast

Comment: More likely than not, you would be instantly vaporized. Also, this question does not have much to do with worldbuilding, since it does not seem to take place in a universe that is fundamentally different from out own. Try posting this on a different stack exchange site if you want an answer.

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://www.sciencealert.com/watch-how-far-away-would-you-need-to-be-to-survive-a-nuclear-blast

Comment: [Wikipedia: Atomic bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki: Bombing of Hiroshima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki#Bombing_of_Hiroshima) gives the radius of total destruction from Little Boy detonating over Hiroshima as "about 1 mile (1.6 km)".

Comment: Could you clarify how this is about building a fictional world? Otherwise, it may be put on hold and ultimately closed as off topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [Help].

Comment: Hi Buzz.  I apologize for using your question as an example, but this question is a good example of a question that should not have been answered by anyone until improved.  It's missing details including where you are, what you're in, what constitutes "survive," why your research wasn't able to answer your question, etc.  As such, the question should have been (and should still be) quickly closed awaiting improvement rather than answered.

Comment: @TheWeaselSagas, [real world questions are acceptable here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate) and I can't think of any other site that would accept this question.  Generally, we should be working to help OPs improve their questions, not turn them away.

Comment: Can't http://nuclearsecrecy.com/nukemap/ help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Here's a breakdown of the effects at different distances for a Bomb the size of Fatman:

1. 600 m: Buildings completely leveled
2. 1.0 km: Railway cars crushed and blown off tracks
3. 1.4 km: Instantly lethal radiation dose
4. 1.7 km: Complete destruction of a majority buildings
5. 1.8 km: Acute radiation syndrome
6. 2.0 km: Conflagration (within the fireball)
7. 2.5 km: 3rd degree burns (you'll probably live if you're in a typical, non-nuclear bomb shelter)
8. 3.2 km: 2nd degree burns
9. 4.2 km: 1st degree burns
10. 4.7 km: Moderate damage to civilian buildings

Beyond this, your survivability depends on the fallout from the nuclear blast, which depends a lot more on the weather and other factors.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the problem is Fat man was the Nagasaki Bomb, not Hiroshima.  You're thinking of Little Boy.  Fat man was the more powerful bomb, but Little Boy was the more destructive (mostly due to terrain blocking a large amount of the blast force.  Hiroshima was flat coastal land that allowed more destructive forces to go further).

To further emphasis that it really depends on just what is getting hit and when, we need to look at two really amazing incidents in Hiroshima.  First, the building known as the Genbaku Dome (A-Bomb Dome) is a pre-Atomic Bomb structure from Hiroshima that is the symbol of the peace memorial.  It was directly under the blast of the explosion and stands as it was found by the survivors.  We also know that the closest known Hiroshima Survivor was Eizo Numura, a bank teller who was in the building's vault some 170 m from ground zero at the time of detonation.  So conditions really depend on where you were and what you were doing when the bomb went off.

For a really good read, TV Tropes has an article (The Deadliest Mushroom) where they discuss what would happen if a Hiroshima style bomb was detonated over Walt Disney Studios in L.A. (We all know this means Bugs said "This Means War" at some point.)

Answer (score 1):

@BUZ  Z I recommend you revisit the original "Terminator" movie, c. 1984...the "judgement day" dream sequence is pretty accurate from a first-hand perspective.  Tests done by U.S. Defense during the cold war on both human 'volunteers' and animal test subjects, all point to the assumption that being 1000 meters from *any* atomic  blast is lethal, death is usually instant as well.

Comment: Survival depends on what is between you and the blast. If you have 1000m of solid rock, e.g. a bunker, or other side of the mountain, you will be safe. 1000m of dirt (e.g. a hill) should keep you safe from Fat Man, but not the more modern thermonuclear bombs. At a few kilometers, hiding in a trench might be enough.

Comment: Still true today, as it was back in the Civil Defense 'Duck and cover' days ... Distance + Time + Shielding

Comment: @Joe small note, Terminator 2: Judgement Day was released in 1991, it was the one with nuclear dream sequence . In 1984, the first Terminator was released.

Comment: @MrAnderson:  Excellent point: I stand corrected - it was Reese's dream in the first movie, those interested can see the judgement day sequence here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6S_5xkvylc